# how to get the time cost of all spring bean initialization

Tags: spring

all

my spring app takes too long to start before it can respond to requests.

so I want to check which were the beans that took the most time, so that I can do something further more.

is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to enable logs, since you don't know which bean is taking long time.

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans.factory=DEBUG
```

You will see something like:

```
DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:450 - Creating instance of bean...
```